# PowerShell to extract value from JSON object, that changes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to extract value from JSON object, I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "aad.NTA5YjRjYTItNDFjNi03OTQ1LTlmNTYtM2MyOGI1NWE5MTU5": {
    "descriptor": "aad.NTA5YjRjYTItNDFjNi03OTQ1LTlmNTYtM2MyOGI1NWE5MTU5",
    "directoryAlias": "dis3yv",
    "displayName": "Tom Test",
    "domain": "ea80952e-a476-42d4-aaf4-5457awesfre",
    "legacyDescriptor": null,
    "mailAddress": "Tom.Test@email.com",
    "metaType": "member",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "919579e1-6e98-47fd-adb3-3d52d0467037",
    "principalName": "Tom.Test@email.com"
  },
  "aad.NmE5ODg4ODQtM2EyNS03ZjBiLWI0OTItN2JmMDA1MzVkNmJi": {
    "descriptor": "aad.NmE5ODg4ODQtM2EyNS03ZjBiLWI0OTItN2JmMDA1MzVkNmJi",
    "directoryAlias": "cup7mz",
    "displayName": "Dummy May",
    "domain": "ea80952e-a476-42d4-aaf4-5457852b0f7e",
    "legacyDescriptor": null,
    "mailAddress": "Dummy.May@mail.com",
    "metaType": "member",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "71e2fa85-59f0-4d8f-a5a9-4ff3e23d01d9",
    "principalName": "James.May@mail.com",
    "subjectKind": "user"
  }
}
```

Here I want to extract **mailaddress** from this file using powershell, and assign it to variable.

The problem I have is the top value "aad.*" keeps changing and I want to be able to automat this so I can have all the mailaddresses in an array or something

so i can't use

```bsh
$yourVariable = (Get-Content 'yourJsonFilePath.json' | ConvertFrom-Json).aad.NTA5YjRjYTItNDFjNi03OTQ1LTlmNTYtM2MyOGI1NWE5MTU5.mailaddress
```

because the value keeps changing

Anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will need to do is `foreach` by the `PSObject.Properties`

For simplicity, I assigned the json to a variable in a the script as an example. You can still call it from a file location:

```
$jsonFile = @'
{
  "aad.NTA5YjRjYTItNDFjNi03OTQ1LTlmNTYtM2MyOGI1NWE5MTU5": {
    "descriptor": "aad.NTA5YjRjYTItNDFjNi03OTQ1LTlmNTYtM2MyOGI1NWE5MTU5",
    "directoryAlias": "dis3yv",
    "displayName": "Tom Test",
    "domain": "ea80952e-a476-42d4-aaf4-5457awesfre",
    "legacyDescriptor": null,
    "mailAddress": "Tom.Test@email.com",
    "metaType": "member",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "919579e1-6e98-47fd-adb3-3d52d0467037",
    "principalName": "Tom.Test@email.com"
  },
  "aad.NmE5ODg4ODQtM2EyNS03ZjBiLWI0OTItN2JmMDA1MzVkNmJi": {
    "descriptor": "aad.NmE5ODg4ODQtM2EyNS03ZjBiLWI0OTItN2JmMDA1MzVkNmJi",
    "directoryAlias": "cup7mz",
    "displayName": "Dummy May",
    "domain": "ea80952e-a476-42d4-aaf4-5457852b0f7e",
    "legacyDescriptor": null,
    "mailAddress": "Dummy.May@mail.com",
    "metaType": "member",
    "origin": "aad",
    "originId": "71e2fa85-59f0-4d8f-a5a9-4ff3e23d01d9",
    "principalName": "James.May@mail.com",
    "subjectKind": "user"
  }
}
'@
```

Convert and `foreach` by `PSObject.Propteries`:

```
#convert
$jsonObject = ($jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json)
#display all Mailaddress
$jsonObject.PSObject.Properties | %{$_.Value.MailAddress}
```

In your example it should just be:

```
$yourVariable.PSObject.Properties | %{$_.Value.MailAddress}
```

If you don't want to `foreach` and you can call it directly like so:

```
$yourVariable.PSObject.Properties.Value.MailAddress
```

The `foreach` allows you to call more than one property value at a time though.